# how to display tags like <?php ?> <script> as text, and <a> as link <table> as table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a variable in PHP that is a string containing HTML. I would like to use the structure of the table and links inside this string, but everything else I would like to escape so it is displayed on the page (like SO does with the code button in the editor). What is the best way to go about this?

This is my latest code attempt but it's not working:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(htmlentities($variable),"<a><table>");
```

*Thought/Logic Process:* I designed a CMS using PHP and MySQL for my class project. I added a `<textarea>` to insert my content (which will be shown in the content area in my HTML page). I want to display tags like `<?php?>` and `<script>` within a HTML page as text. I did that using `htmlentities();`.

However with `htmlentities();`, tags like `<a>` and `<table>` are also shown as text. I can use the `strip_tags(,"<a><table>");` function to avoid that, but with the `strip_tags();` function it is not possible to display tags like `<?php ?>` `</script>` as a text.

How do I do this?

Is there a way to use these both function on one `$variable`

Example:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(htmlentities($variable),"<a><table>");
```

Comment: You might want to clarify your question a bit.  It's not exactly clear what you are asking.   Also, including a sample of your code is always helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In html 
<pre> tag is used to show html tags as text

<pre> <h1></pre> will be displayed <h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think I understand your question like this...

You want to put a table on your web page, but inside that table you want to be able to display "special characters" and still retain the table structure as well as any links.

You should basically pull the data out of the variable and parse it like this ...

```
$HTML[] = '<table><tr><td>';
$HTML[] = strip_tags(htmlentities($cellContent);
$HTML[] = '</td></tr></table>';

foreach ($HTML as $v) {
    echo $v;
}
```

Comment: yup...<?php echo strip_tags(htmlentities($variable),"<a><table>");

Comment: I just faced same question in this site, i posted my codes with the question but the codes are not displayed.

Comment: If I was the first to answer correctly can you please click the check mark to the left of my answer to accept it as the correct answer.  :)   Thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: i just edited my question. if you can pls read that and answer me..thanks

Comment: this is why you need to post better code in your question because I would be able to tell easier what your trying to do.  I'll post an example of the code you should have posted in your question so you can get an idea.

Comment: btw i only ask you to make your question nicer becasue I would really like to upvote it.

Comment: what a punk, that other guy deleted his post and downvoted me cuz he was butthurt that i answered first and better than him.

Comment: can you click the up arrow next to my question @Hirantha you know I deserve it :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Let me know if you run into any other issues.  Thanks for the upvote :)